# Is it possible to git pull but ignore locations that were symlinked or no longer exist

Tags: git

Here is my use case.
I have a repository that contains a storage directory like so:

```
<project>
  public/
    index.php
  src/
    ...
  var/
    media/
      .gitkeep
    documents/
      .gitkeep
      sample1.csv
      sample2.csv
```

Sample documents are used by unit tests and are not needed in production.

Now I installed application and replaced `media` and `documents` directories with symlinks to a shared filesystem (nfs), so now I have this structure:

```
<project>
  public/
    index.php
  src/
    ...
  var/
    media/ -> /data/<project>/media
    documents/ -> /data/<project>/documents
```

Works fine, but if I will add `sample3.csv` for another unit test then `git pull` will no longer be able to work (it will complain about the symlink).
Since I have automatic deployments (`git pull` is run by a script, not manually), this is a big problem for me.

Is there a way to tell git pull, to just ignore files that it cannot pull, or even better to ignore certain directories?

Comment: Pull just means "run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command" which by default is `git merge`. Merging your own code, where you didn't touch `var/media/.gitkeep` at all, with someone else's commits, where they removed `/var/media/.gitkeep` entirely and created `/var/media` as a symlink, will take their change without any conflicts. You'll only get conflicts if *you* modified `.gitkeep` or added new files, or made a change to a *different* symlink, etc.

Comment: In your case, it's the other way around: you've made this change, but as long as *they* didn't touch *their* stuff, Git will keep your changes. Again, there's no *conflict*.

Comment: But, if you and they have made *different changes*, which will be the case for when they add a new file and you haven't yet merged your changes to replace all this with symlinks, then you'll have a problem, yes. But: no, there's no royal road around this. That's a "high level" / "tree level" conflict, and the `-X` options won't help you here. You'll just have to resolve the conflict.

Comment: There's one way to avoid the conflict: don't use `git merge`. But that's probably a cure worse than the disease. There's probably nothing superior to just resolving the conflict.

Comment: Here's a suggested modification to your design: put your unit test files in another folder, say `var-test/`, and make `var/media` and `var/documents` symlinks to `var-test/*` in your branch, and symlinks as you describe in the production branch. There might be a conflict on the first merge, but after that it should be fine.

Comment: With this idea, you would keep `var-test/` in both production and dev branches, so that adding new test files will not cause conflicts on the next pull. And if you really don't want `var-test/` to exist on your production server, add `rm -r var-test` to your automatic deployment script/recipe.

Comment: The unit test was only an example, I would prefer something more reliable, but I kinda like the idea of storing symlink in repo. The only issue I see is that now I need to know what will be symlinked on production, so code depends on deployment while it should be the other way around.